# .php files are not associated with Zend Studio

Tags: zend-studio

after reinstalling ZS 9.0.1 on Vista i can't make .php files be opened with it by default.

The files are opening in another program (EditPlus in my case) instead of ZS. This happens when clicking files on file system (Desktop) and in Remote Connections.

When i try to change properties of .php files in Windows, SZ does not appear in the list of programs, even if i click "Browse" and locate the .exe in Program Files.

The only way to open the files is to drag them to ZS.

How this can be fixed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can map file extension to editors by this

[src](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-13.htm)

Comment: yes, i have *.php in 'Content Types' and 'PHP Editor (default) (locked by PHP Content Type)

Answer (score 0):

Yes but that's not what the link Mr Coder posted tells you to do. You need to go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors ->  File Associations, add/select the extension, select the PHP editor, and click default. This will make it use that editor. I just found this answer and did that, and it works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this:

First, window > preference > general > editor > file associations > add(.php) > php(default)

Next, select PHP file in remote system explore or etc. > click right button > open with > Select Default editor.

The last action is very important.